# How to embed hex values in a lua string literal (i.e. \x equivalent)

Tags: string, lua, escaping, hex, string-literals

In various languages, you can embed hex values in a string literal by using the \x escape sequence:

`"hello \x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64"`

How can I do the same thing in Lua 5.1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Lua 3.1, you can use *decimal* escapes in strings liberals.

Starting with Lua 5.2, you can use hex escapes in string literals.

In Lua 5.1, you can convert hex escapes a posteriori:

```
s=[[hello \x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64]]
s=s:gsub("\\x(%x%x)",function (x) return string.char(tonumber(x,16)) end)
print(s)
```

Note the use of *long strings*, which do not interpret escape sequences. If you use *short strings* (in quotes) as in  your original code, then `\x` will be silently converted to `x`, because Lua 5.1 does not understand `\x`. Lua 5.2 and later complains about escape sequences that it does not understand.

Comment: I like this answer because you explain how to go about doing exactly what I asked, even though the language doesn't support it be default. I think if you can reference the existing ability to embed _decimal_ values in string literals (i.e. combine my answer and yours), then I'll accept this answer.

Comment: any idea why this seems to work for me in 5.1?!
    `print(_VERSION, '\xff') >>>  Lua 5.1 \255`

Comment: @NasBanov, perhaps you're running LuaJIT instead of Lua from lua.org.

Comment: @lhf you got it! I was trying in ZeroBrane Studio console and when not debugging it is indeed LuaJIT (has `jit` table). When i debug at a breakpoint though, no more JIT and the output is `"Lua 5.1" "xff"` - perfect match!

Answer (score 3):

(From the [Lua 5.1 reference](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html))

You can embed *decimal* values in a string literal in Lua by using the `\ddd` escape sequence, where `ddd` is a sequence of up to three *decimal digits*. For example:

`"\72ell\111"` is the same as `"hello"`

Comment: If you are using decimal value on strings that mix control and regular characters, I suggest you *always* use 3 positions (and not up-to-3) or convert *all* characters, otherwise you are risking turning "\n3" into "\103", which is not the same as "\0103"

Comment: Agreed, I was surprised when I saw the "up to three" statement in the documentation and felt it was nothing but trouble!